# Can you mock system functionality in a pytest fixture?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have the following class which does a bunch of system level stuff like call `os.system`, `mkdir` and make HTTP requests for example:

```
# mymodule.scene.py
import os
from pathlib import Path
import requests

class Scene:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.do_stuff_1(id)
        self.do_stuff_2(id)

    def do_stuff_1(self, id):
        path = Path(f'/fake/cache/folder/{id}')
        path.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
        os.system(f'gsutil cp gs://myfile.txt /fake/cache/folder/{id}/myfile.txt')

    def do_stuff_2(self, id):
        resp = requests.get(f'http://www.google.com/{id}').json()
        return resp['status'] == 'OK'
```

I would like to create a `pytest.fixture` which injects this class while having all the `os`, `pathlib` and `requests` calls mocked:

```
#tests/conftest.py
@pytest.fixture
def scene(mocker):
    # mocker.patch.object( ..
    # How do I mock Path, mkdir and os.system in the fixture
    scene = Scene()
    return scene
```

So I can test them as follows:

```
# tests/test_scene.py
def test_do_stuff_1(scene):
    scene.do_stuff_1(123)
    # ? How do I assert Path, mkdir and os.system were called

def test_do_stuff_2(scene):
    scene.do_stuff_2(456)
    # ? How do I assert requests get as called
```

My question is how to I do the mocking in the fixture and then access the mocked methods in the tests to confirm they were called with the correct parameters and mock the return values?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want them all patched in the same fixture? Is there a reason for this (instead of using separate fixtures for separate functions)? You still have to access the mocks separately, so I see no gain in for example returning a tuple of mocks from one fixture as opposed to just yield one mock from one fixture as usual.

Comment: I do just want one mock yielded from the fixture. But I want all three methods patched in one place

Comment: You can of course patch them in the same fixture, but how do you want to check for the different function calls if you have only the scene returned? There is no connection between the scene and the mocked functions, as far as I can see. I seem to be missing something here...

Comment: The fixture handled that and automatically adds it as a parameter when the test is called.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "that" and "it", maybe you can add that information to the question.

Comment: Are you familiar with what a fixture does in pytest? I can add some details to the question if it's helpful.

Comment: Yes, I know what a fixture is in pytest, and that you patch some attributes there. What I don't get is how you want to access them. To check for example if `os.system` has been called, you need the mock object created by the patching, as there is no way to get to it from the scene. If you don't save it anywhere and don't return it I don't know how you want to access it. I don't understand what do you mean by "the fixture automatically adds it as a parameter" - your fixture is not set to `autouse`, and a fixture does not  automatically set a parameter in a test.

Comment: The commented lines are where I'm hoping to do the patching and then the assertions. I'm just not sure what that actual code is. My objective is not to have to do the patching of this class in every single test (there are many of them) I want to patch is in the fixture once instead @MrBeanBremen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from the comments I understood that you have a number of tests that all need some properties mocked, and also need the scene constructed in a fixture. You sometimes need to check some of the mocks for a called method, but not in all tests and not all methods.

Assuming I understood that correctly, I would make separate fixtures for the mocks that you need to check, so you will be able to access them if needed, and then "derive" the scene from them, e.g. something like this (out of my head):

```py
@pytest.fixture
def mocked_request(mocker):
    mocked = mocker.patch.object(...)
    yield mocked

@pytest.fixture
def mocked_system(mocker):
    yield mocker.patch("os.system")

@pytest.fixture
def scene(mocked_request, mocked_system, ...)
   yield Scene()

def test_do_stuff_1(scene, mocked_system):
    scene.do_stuff_1(123)
    mocked_system.assert_called_with(...)

def test_do_stuff_2(scene, mocked_request):
    scene.do_stuff_2(456)
    mocked_request.assert_called_once()
```

This is under the assumption that you need the patching only with the scene.
If you need the patching applied independently from the scene, you can just make them `autouse` instead:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mocked_request(mocker):
    mocked = mocker.patch.object(...)
    yield mocked

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mocked_system(mocker):
    yield mocker.patch("os.system")

@pytest.fixture
def scene()
   ...
```

In order to check for called methods, you *need* to have access to the mock instances, so your approach of using only one fixture will not work (except you return a tuple or a dictionary with all the mocks from the fixture, but that would be inconvenient to use).